# SQL - Calculate Hours sum using rollup

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I am looking to get sum of all hours as summary in last row. I am using the following query to get result:

```
create table time_test (type varchar(10),time varchar(10))
insert into time_test values ('A','01:25')
insert into time_test values ('B','02:30')
insert into time_test values ('C','05:56')
insert into time_test values ('D','00:50')

--select * from time_test

SELECT
  type = ISNULL(type, 'Total'),
  time = substring((cast(sum(((cast(substring (time,2,1) as decimal)*60 + cast(substring (time,4,2) as decimal))/60)) as varchar(10))),1,2)+':' + cast((cast((round(((cast((((cast((substring((cast((sum(((cast(substring (time,2,1) as decimal)*60 + cast(substring (time,4,2) as decimal))/60))) as varchar(10))),4,2)) as int))*60)) as decimal)/100)),0)) as int)) as varchar(10))
FROM time_test
GROUP BY ROLLUP(type);
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

As you can see time is not coming correct beside this total calculation is working fine.

**Problem:**
Please let me know where i am working wrong during showing the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have similar requirement  and solved it like this:

```
select type, RTRIM(time/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(time%60),2) from
( 
    select type= ISNULL(type, 'Total'),
      time= SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', time))
    from time_test
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(type)
) x
```

I believe this is more understandable and easier to trace

```
type    time
A       1:25
B       2:30
C       5:56
D       0:50
Total   10:41
```

**Edit: Updated the query for `hour can be more then 24 hours`**

```
select type, RTRIM(time/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(time%60),2) from
( 
    select type= ISNULL(type, 'Total'),
      time= SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', 
        DATEADD(day, SUBSTRING(time,0,CHARINDEX(':',time,0)) / 24,
        DATEADD(hour, SUBSTRING(time,0,CHARINDEX(':',time,0)) % 24, 
        DATEADD(minute,SUBSTRING(time,CHARINDEX(':',time)+1,LEN(time)) +0, 0)) )))
    from time_test
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(type)
) x
```

Example Result:

```
A       1:25
B       2:30
C       5:56
D       70:50
Total   80:41
```

Comment: I am getting: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 168
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. as in my case hours may exceed two digit length. like 120:00.

Comment: please check my updated answer. if it works, please accept it as answer. thank you :)

Comment: Thnaks Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would firstly fix your datatype, a time should be stored as a `time`, not a `varchar`. Then, once you've fixed your datatype you can treat your data as what it is (a time).

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.time_test ([type] varchar(10),
                            [time] time);
INSERT INTO dbo.time_test
VALUES ('A', '01:25'); --Assumes hh:mm
INSERT INTO dbo.time_test
VALUES ('B', '02:30');
INSERT INTO dbo.time_test
VALUES ('C', '05:56');
INSERT INTO dbo.time_test
VALUES ('D', '00:50');
GO

SELECT ISNULL([type],'Total') AS [Type],
       DATEADD(MINUTE,SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'00:00',[time])),CONVERT(time(0),'00:00')) AS [Time]
FROM dbo.time_test
GROUP BY [type] WITH ROLLUP;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.time_test;
```

This returns:

```
Type       Time
---------- ----------------
A          01:25:00
B          02:30:00
C          05:56:00
D          00:50:00
Total      10:41:00
```

Comment: Use seconds instead of minutes for more accurate result.

Comment: @SalmanA we don't know what `'05:56'` in the OP's sample. That *assumes* their data is `mm:ss`. I've assumed `hh:mm` (per the comment in the SQL), but we have no way of actually knowing without them telling us.

Comment: One more question as i using varchar type, can we do this using varchar type only by conversion?

Comment: @Sunny why not correct your datatype in your table? That is by far the better option. Otherwise you *could* convert the value `[time]` to a `time` (Oh the irony, a column called `[time]` isn't a `time`) in the expression, yes.

Comment: Actually this is a temp table in my SP, after calculating fields from other set of tables i am getting these values.

Comment: @Larnu I need only hours and minutes(HH:MM) in result how i can do this? Currently result is coming with seconds.

Comment: @Larnu I am getting: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 168
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. as in my case hours may exceed two digit length. like 120:00.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so quick code review, try to avoid using VARCHAR datatype for storing date and/or time.

below is what I did:

```
create table time_test (type varchar(10),time1 time)
insert into time_test values ('A','00:01:30')
insert into time_test values ('B','00:02:30')
insert into time_test values ('C','00:01:00')
insert into time_test values ('D','00:02:30')

SELECT
  type = ISNULL(type, 'Total'),
  seconds_worked = SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00', time1))
  FROM time_test
GROUP BY ROLLUP(type);
```

you will see the Total comes to 450, which if you calculate manually from the supplied data appears to be right, i.e. the total time is 450 seconds.

you can use the below formula to return your time in mins and seconds:

```
RTRIM(**450**/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(**450**%60),2)
```

Comment: oh yeah, forgot to remove <br> after SELECT, you can do this by yourself

Comment: just did, thanks, trying to adapt to the formatting here.